# Android: Get clicked view inside Listview item

Tags: android, listview

I read many threads and did a lot of tests but without success.

In an Activity I have a listview connected to an adapter of type ResourceCursorAdapter.

In the method (bindView) of the adapter I defined the custom layout of every row of the listview.

Every row has 2 ImageButton, 2 TextView and 1 Checkbox: the layout is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".Main"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chebag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="8" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texbag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="68"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:lines="3"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/butdec"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/meno" 
        android:clickable="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/texnum"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="100"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/butinc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/piu"
        android:clickable="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the Activity I prepared the listener of the listview of name (lismain); with the syntax of the layout **every click
in the list item triggers** the method (onItemClick).

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mainlistener=   new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,final int position, long id) {


    }
};

lismain.setOnItemClickListener(mainlistener);
```

I need these 2 things:
a) when in (onItemClick) **I cannot identify which child view was clicked by the user** 
(the row itself or the ImageButtons inside: to have a different processing)

b) I prefer to handle the click events **in the Activity** and not in the adapter: it would be also fine if the ImageButtons trigger for example the (onClick) method, but I tried also without success.

Thanks for the support

Comment: Just check this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer, but at the end I solved the problem with the example here:
http://wiresareobsolete.com/2011/08/clickable-zones-in-listview-items/

The fundamental steps of the link are:

a) the class with the Adapter of the listview is an **inner class** of the calling Activity.
For example we can call Main the Activity class and MyAdapter the class with type Adapter.

b) The ImageButton in the row layout of the listview is called (butinc):
we call butinc.setOnClickListener(Main.this) in the method (bindView).

```
public class MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            ImageButton  butinc =   (ImageButton)   view.findViewById(R.id.butinc);

            butinc.setOnClickListener(Main.this);

        }

}
```

c) When the ImageButton is pressed by the user in the listview row and the right properties are set in the layout,
for example android:clickable, the click is handled in the OnClick method of Main activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick (View v) {

    if(v.getId() == R.id.butinc) {

        // the code here handles the button click
    }
}
```

d) The activity class is for example declared as:

```
public class Pres extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

// the Onclick method handles the interface View.OnClickListener

}
```

Doing all these steps, the button click is handled by methods in the class of type Activity.

Comment: I didn't have any problem registering an onClick event in the XML for the Item List and having it execute in the Activity. But with parameter View, how do you do anything useful. Because I don't know how to get to the Cursor data associated with that row. The onItemClick() event at least as the position and id of the data in question, and you can get the Cursor row using listView.getItemAtPosition(position) to access the data. So how do you do anything meaningful from the onClick event of the imageButton?